# If we see Menses in dreams should we have to take ghusul

Tags: menses

If a female see as she is having her Menses or blood or something related to the Menses,, does ghusul get wajib on her or she can continue her Salah n recitation of Quran

Comment: Ghusl is required for known set of things which you should be able to look up easily. Everything else (including dreams of menses) do not require ghusl.

Answer (score 1):

If you see menses in your dream that does not make you impure. If you see menses blood out then after your period you have to purify yourself by doing ghusl because menses blood is considered impure.

Answer (score 1):

You are required to perform *Ghusl* if you are actually having menses in reality, not in your dreams.

To simplify, it is like asking *would I be executed if I killed someone in my dreams or saw myself killing someone.* I hope you get my point.